# What does the query 'show innodb status' in MySQL mean?

Tags: mysql, innodb

What does the query `show innodb status` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Show innodb status walkthrough](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/17/show-innodb-status-walk-through/)

SHOW INNODB STATUS is command which prints out a lot of internal Innodb performance counters, statistics, information about transaction processing and all kinds of other things. In MySQL 5 number of Innodb performance counters were exported and now available in SHOW STATUS output. Most of them are same as you previously could find in SHOW INNODB STATUS, there are however few which were not available before ...